# Can I launch my goat into space in Goat Simulator?

Tags: goat-simulator

I recently overheard my friend claiming he could launch his goat into space(or a very high point whatsoever) , but he didn't tell me how, and told me to "do it myself". I'm intrigued by this challenge, so I decided to test it out, but it seemed impossible to launch myself that high. Is it even possible, or is my friend making a false claim?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite launching, but it's possible your friend was describing being taken into space by a UFO.

Bring the B(e)acon from the Starter House garage to the Crop Circles and place it on the empty pedestal. This isn't possible on the Mobile edition.

([Source](https://goatsimulator.gamepedia.com/Space))